# change the desktop appearance from my new version 12.10 to the old 10.04

Tags: 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

I've just upgraded my machine from 10.04 to the new 12.10.
How do I change the desktop appearance from my new version 12.10 to the old 10.04 so the rest of the family can get to grips with the PC?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do so would be by installing an *alternative desktop environment*. You could add the Xubuntu or Lubuntu desktops to give you the GNOME 2 look by running `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` or `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` and then logging into whichever desktop environment you want.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can install gnome-session-fallback and make a few additional tweaks to make your desktop almost the same (but not perfectly so) as that of 10.04.  See, for example:
http://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/time-for-more-long-term-support/  The foregoing relates to 12.04 vs. 10.04, but the same processes should work for 12.10.